# SQL Server 2005 SP3 version 9.00.4035.00 vs 9.00.4053.00

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005

We manage a bunch of SQL server installations for clients and we're seeing different reported version numbers for SQL Server 2005 SP3.  Some report 9.00.4035.00 and others report 9.00.4053.00.  Copied/pasted, not typed, it's not a typo or transposition.

We're getting version number with this SQL:

```
SELECT SERVERPROPERTY('productversion') productversion, SERVERPROPERTY ('productlevel') productlevel
```

This KB article says the latest is 9.00.4035.00.  I can't find any documentation on where 9.00.4053.00 came from but I did find lots of references from various forum posts referring to it.

Both servers were upgraded with MS Update only, no special hotfixes or anything like that.

Can anyone explain the difference?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Security update:  http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?familyid=0d878f4b-71e8-4170-9a14-1bce684811ce&displaylang=en